Pip can't install packages in an entreprise Python installation
I'm working for a company that has a lot of security restrictions hence they have their own distribution of Python via miniforge3. For some reason, when I'm trying to install libraries in a venv in PyCharm (pip install numpy), it doesn't find the location and can't install it (see image), although it works when using pip "globally" (without any virtual environment). I had a look at the different file in /venv/Scripts but I can't find out why it doesn't work. The weird thing is that my colleague has exactly the same install for everything and there's no issue.
Any idea?
enter image description here
I'm expecting pip to install packages

For me when I have just started the new folder and project, i just delete it and make a new one and it seems to always work. If you are not able to do that, you can reset your powershell path and re-add the path, that seems to work aswell.

Sometimes recreating the virtual environment can resolve issues. Delete the existing venv folder and create a new one using
python -m venv venv

if it fails try updating pip and setuptools this may  solve SSL issues
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

